# Technical reason for static java.net design

Tags: java

Is there any technical reason that java.net.Authenticator uses a static `setDefault()`, has no `getDefault()` (so you can, worst case, wrap it) and can not be overriden on a per-instance method when used by say http?

Same question for other classes like `java.net.CookieHandler`: why a `static` default? Why no per-instance settings?

I can understand that perhaps it was designed in version 1.0 when application servers weren't a thing, but why hasn't the per-instance functionality been added to the appropriate classes? Currently I always have to use other libraries to do basic things like HTTP.

This question is not meant as flamebait, I'm genuinely curious if there are some technical limitations that my google-fu can't find.